# Can having too many activities be an issue?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating an app that will ask questions once a button is pressed; it will determine what activity and layout to take the user to next. I’ve been creating activities for each question that is asked, but am curious about whether too many activities can hurt an app. Does it really matter?

Comment: too many ?? How many activities do you have in your project ?

Comment: You should look into fragments or just update your view if you are displaying the save layout on each activity.

Comment: If there is any similarity at all, most would do this with a small number of activities which load the textual content for each of a larger database of questions in turn.  You could also consider an html(/javascript) solution in a WebView, but that seems to be a bit of a moving target with new quirks in each Android release.

Comment: As Of Right Now I Have 50 Activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)-**An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do**.Based on this definition you can determine whether you want one activity or many..I your scenario I feel multiple activities for each question is not desired.

Comment: As I Stated Im Still Very New To Programing In General And Chose to Start With Android Apps So You Mise well Call Me A GreenHorn But Designing A Activity And Layout Then Configuring Button Onclick  Is Bout The Only Thing Ive Kinda Got Down Pat And Understand Thats Why I Have Went As Far As 50 Activities Just Because Thats Bout All I Know At The Moment Thats Why I Wanted To Get Some Of Others Inputs Because Thanks To This Site It Has Helped Me Solve Several Issues That I Have Had I Totally Recomend This Sight To Those in Need Thats Why Im Here

Comment: Just have a single activity and change the content when the user clicks on particular view..refer http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/220-lesson-16-creating-layout-programmatically-layoutparams.html

Comment: Thank You rupesh But IS There A Such Thing As Too Many Activities Or Too Many Hurting The App?

Comment: @CharlesHouser ya it will hurt the performance of the app because there is bookeeping involved with each activity creation..Also from development perspective its not convenient..its like buying a new car everytime you have to go somewhere..

Comment: Ok I Understand what Your Saying That Makes Alot Of Sense .. That Was My Main Wonder And Concern

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have multiple questions that use the same activity, there is no reason to be creating additional activities. You can always store what the user answered, and do the following after:

```
// On answering a question, do this...

this.question = "Is this my new question?";
this.answers = new String[]
{
    "Answer A",
    "Answer B",
    "Answer C",
    "Answer D"
}

this.onCreate(bundle);
```

Just be sure that your activity's onCreate method does not initialize these variables. I prefer calling this.onCreate() as opposed to this.recreate(), as the activity seamlessly updates, without a flicker.

Comment: I Have Been Using This Method To Assign To Buttons Onclick BasicallyTo Start Another Activity And Just A Routine Cycle 



//

public void NameOfCommand(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Goto.class));
        finish();
    }